# Query resolver error: "Variable \"$productId\" of required type \"ID!\" was not provided."

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, mern

I can't seem to figure out the issue when trying to create an ID. I've tried doing

```
createProduct: async(parent,{name,price,description}) => {
 return Product.create({name,price,description});
}
```

and incorporating the ID in updateProduct, instead.

```
updateProduct: async(parent,{id,name,price,description}) => {
return Product,fineOneandUpdate(
{_id: id},
{$set:{name,price,description}},
{new:true}
);}, // Comma to go to the deleteProduct
```

```
const resolvers = {
Query: {
  getProduct: async (parent, {productId}) =>{
    return Product.find.one({
      _id: productId //specific product
    });
  },
 getAllProduct: async() => {
  return Product.find({productId}); //empty ID might return all products
 }
 },
 Mutation:{
  createProduct: async(parent,{id,name,price,description}) => {
    return Product.create({id,name,price,description}); //mutation will create new product
  },
  updateProduct: async(parent,{id,name,price,description}) => {
    return Product.findOneAndUpdate( //mutation will update product
      {_id: id},
      {$set: {name,price,description}},
      {new: true}
    );
  },
  deleteProduct: async(parent,{id}) => {
    return Product.findOneAndDelete({_id: id}); //mutation will delete product
  }
 }
}
```

```
const {resolvers} = require('./resolvers');
const typeDefs = `
  type Product {
    _id: ID!
    name: String!
    price: Float!
    description: String!
  }
  
  type Query {
    getProduct(productId:ID!): Product
    getAllProduct: [Product]
  }
  type Mutation {
    createProduct(id: ID!,name: String!, price: Float!, description: String!): Product
    updateProduct(id: ID!, name: String!, price: Float!, description: String!): Product
    deleteProduct(id: ID!): Product
  }
`;
```

Then for the models, i have three files, index.js,items.js,Tech.js(Ignore this one).

The items.js file has

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');

const itemSchema = new Schema({
  item1: {
    id:{
      type: Number,
      required: true
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    price: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  item2: {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    price: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  item3: {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    price: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  item4: {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    price: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  item5: {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    price: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  item6: {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    price: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
},
);

const Items = model('items', itemSchema);
module.exports = Items;
```

I've trying incorporating the ID in their too. But i can't seem to tell what i'm doing wrong because in "localhost:3001/graphql", i do

```
query Query($productId: ID!) {
  getProduct(productId: $productId) {
    _id
    name
    description
  }
}
```

and in return I get

```
{
  "data": {},
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Variable \"$productId\" of required type \"ID!\" was not provided.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 1,
          "column": 13
        }
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "BAD_USER_INPUT",
        "stacktrace": [
          "GraphQLError: Variable \"$productId\" of required type \"ID!\" was not provided."
```